# How to compare date string using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have the following **string value** of a date, `Sun Apr 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300`, and I need to **compare** with the following date format `2019-04-08T03:00:00.000Z`, note that both are the same day, I need to compare them and return a true as being equal days,

but I do not know how to do this using javascript, any help?

I tried to do something like this but it does not return me true:

```
if (input) { 

     //input.value = "Sun Apr 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)"

     var situation = angular.isArray(item.situation) ? item.situation : [item.situation]; 

     // situation = 
     //[
     //    0: "2019-04-08T03:00:00.000Z"
     //    1: "2019-04-13T03:00:00.000Z"
     //]

     if (!angular.isArray(input.value)) {
        condition = situation.indexOf(input.value) >= 0;

     } else if (angular.isArray(input.value)) {
        condition = $window._.intersection(situation, input.value).length > 0;
     }
}

if (condition) {
    break;
}
```

**`//input.value = "Sun Apr 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)"`**

```
 situation = 
     [
         0: "2019-04-08T03:00:00.000Z"
         1: "2019-04-13T03:00:00.000Z"
     ]
```

Comment: What are your criteria for "same day"? Do you want the same UTC day, local day, or for a particular offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sun Apr 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300
>
> 2019-04-08T03:00:00.000Z
>
> note that both are the same day

No, they are not.

You can convert them both to ISO string and just compare their date parts as strings (if I understood the question correctly, you want to compare date only, without time):

```js
function isSameDate(date1, date2) {
  const [d1, ] = (new Date(date1)).toISOString().split('T');
  const [d2, ] = (new Date(date2)).toISOString().split('T');
  return d1 === d2;
}
```

Comment: Which could be: `let isSameDate = (d0, d1) => new Date(d0).toDateString() == new Date(d1).toDateString();`. :-) But only because the timestamps are supported by the ECMAScript 2018 or later. Implementations supporting previous versions may fail at parsing.

Comment: @RobG `.toDateString()` will convert date to your local timezone, whereas `.toISOString()` will convert to UTC. That could be the source of issues, that's why I choose the latter, but thanks for your input :)

Comment: My suggestion compares them as local, yours compares them as UTC. It doesn't matter, as long as they are both converted to the same offset for the comparison.

Comment: @RobG In most cases you'd be right, but as this code probably will be run on frontend it could produce different results for clients with different timezones.

Comment: Certainly, but the same issue occurs whether UTC or local is used as the epoch.

Comment: @RobG Nope. Using UTC we can be sure that results of date comparisons will be the same for all clients regardless of their local timezone. But if we're using client's local timezone then results will differ from client to client for the same date comparisons. Consider two dates: `2019-04-07T02:00:00.000Z` and `2019-04-07T23:00:00.000Z`, for clients with `UTC+3` the `isSameDate` will return `false`, but for clients with `UTC-1` it will be `true`, and for clients with `UTC-3` it will be `false` again.

Comment: @RobG But if we'll use `toISOString` then result for _all_ mentioned clients will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all the values to `Date` objects and compare those. Use a framework/library to do it, because parsing strings to dates manually has lots of places where it can go wrong.

Currently you are comparing the literal `String`s. Because neither `"2019-04-08T03:00:00.000Z"`, nor `"2019-04-13T03:00:00.000Z"` match `"Sun Apr 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)"`, your second `if` statement fails.

Answer (score -1):

Build a date from the strings and compare the days (ie number of seconds since epoch / number of seconds in a day):

```js
const sameDay = (dateString1, dateString2) => {
  let time1 = (new Date(dateString1)).getTime();
  let time2 = (new Date(dateString2)).getTime();
  return Math.floor(Math.abs((time1-time2))/(1000*60*60*24))==0;
}

console.log(
  sameDay('Sun Apr 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)','2019-04-08T03:00:00.000Z'),
  sameDay('Sun Apr 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)','2019-04-13T03:00:00.000Z'),
);
```